# Find min date for each stage of a process

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a process stages I need to find when did they happen. Unfortunately I can only do it though text extraction.
I have extracted dates that match the stages found in the associated text column. Unfortunately some text values are similar and were inputed to the table incorrectly, and so extracted dates are duplicated.
I cannot edit the existing table, however, I am trying to create a new one based on the manipulations I am doing (text extract, date ordering, etc).
I need to make sure that the dates are not mixed up and are consecutive. For example stage 1 date is earlier than stage 2 etc...

Data sample

| Person_ID | Stage | Stage_Num | Stage_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage-1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Stage-1 | 1 | 2021-02-02 |
| 1 | Stage-2 | 2 | 2020-05-01 |
| 1 | Stage-2 | 2 | 2020-05-06 |
| 1 | Stage-1-R | 3 | 2021-02-02 |
| 1 | Stage-1-R | 3 | 2020-01-01 |

Final result I am expecting is

| Person_ID | Stage | Stage Num | Stage_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage-1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Stage-2 | 2 | 2020-05-01 |
| 1 | Stage-1-R | 3 | 2021-02-02 |

I've tried the following:

```
select a.person_id,a.stage, a.stage_num, min(a.stage_date)   
from
all_activity_dates a   join all_activity_dates b   
where
a.stage_num<=b.stage_num   
and a.stage_date<b.stage_date   
group by
a.person_id, a.stage, a.stage_num   
order by stage_num
```

However, the result date for stage 1 and 3 turn out to be the same.
How do I perform it correctly?

*UPD1* To whoever closed my question: I cannot simply select the min and group by STAGE (I definitely know how to do that)
In my original question I state I need consecutive order, but with simple MIN DATE STAGE 1 and STAGE 3 would have the SAME DATE , BUT STAGE 3 HAS to be AFTER STAGE 2.

*UPD2* Plus for stages I am missing to extract date I'd need to add a random date between previous and next stage

If it is a duplicate, I. am glad to check a working solution, I just could not find a similarly worded question

Comment: For each stage, do you want the earliest date that is later than any of the dates on earlier stages?    And are you looking for a query that can handle many stages (not just 3?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that  will at least filter out the dates that would mess up the order of Stage_num.

> ```
> select Person_ID, Stage, Stage_Num
> , max(Stage_Date) as Stage_Date
> from your_table t
> where not exists (
>         select 1 
>         from your_table t2
>         where t2.person_id = t.person_id
>           and t2.stage_num = t.stage_num + 1
>         group by t2.person_id, t2.stage_num
>         having max(t2.stage_date) < t.stage_date
>    )
> group by Person_ID, Stage, Stage_Num
> order by Person_ID, Stage_Num;
> ```

| Person_ID | Stage | Stage_Num | Stage_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage-1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Stage-2 | 2 | 2020-05-06 |
| 1 | Stage-1-R | 3 | 2021-02-02 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad2d84c1c665adf651536ef6c7137331)*

But the thing about adding the missing Stage_nums with a random stage name & date is too unclear.
You could left join to a tally table.  Or just add them manually.

Comment: Thank you! I will see what I can figure out where the dates are missing, but for dups this work perfectly